# Algebra problem solving question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Jo chooses 3 whole numbers between 1 and 40.

The first number is a multiple of 4.

The second number is 6 less than the first number.

The third number is 1/2 the second number.

Difference between the 1st and 3rd number is 21.

What are the three numbers?

What I did:

1st number:$4x$

2nd number:$4x - 6$

Third number:$2x-3$

But when I do:
2x - 3 - 4x = 21
I get x = 12 and so all the numbers are over 40 so it is wrong.

Thank You and help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the last equation should be $4x - (2x-3)$

Comment: O yes now I get the right answer. Thank You!

Comment: Actually you'd get x=-12. If the first number is 4x and the second is 4x-6, then you should have noticed that the numbers are getting smaller....

Comment: 12 is not a solution of 2x - 3 - 4x = 21 (plug in 12 for x)

Answer (score 1):

It is difference between 1st and 3rd hence it will be $\\$ 4x-2x + 3 = 21 $\\$ 2x = 18 and x= 9 . Thus numbers are 36 , 30, 15